# Yum: older removed package conflicting wth new package to install

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, docker

I am trying to upgrade/install docker-engine on Centos7.I had previously installed docker version 1.10. I removed it using yum remove. Currently I am trying to install version 1.12 from the curl script mentioned on the docker website

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

However I am getting the following errors:

```
[root@centos-512mb-nyc3-01 ~]# yum install docker-engine
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cc.columbia.edu
 * extras: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
 * updates: mirror.netdepot.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker-engine.x86_64 0:1.12.3-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: docker-engine-selinux >= 1.12.3-1.el7.centos for package: docker-engine-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7()(64bit) for package: docker-engine-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker-engine-selinux.noarch 0:1.12.3-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.4.2-21.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: docker-engine-selinux-1.12.3-1.el7.centos.noarch conflicts docker-selinux
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: docker-engine-selinux conflicts with docker-selinux-1.10.3-46.el7.centos.14.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Using the solutions prescribed the installation fails due to dependencies. Please help.

Comment: Remove the existing docker-engine-selinux package using yum